# Programatically adding "New Custom Field" To Google Contacts using Google contact API

Tags: c#, api, gmail, contacts

How to create new "Custom Field into Google Contact using Google Contact API (c#)?

I used:

```
ExtendedProperty obj_ExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty(); 
 obj_ExtendedProperty.Name             = "Department";
 obj_ExtendedProperty.Value            = "Sales";
 ContactEntry.ExtendedProperties.Add(obj_ExtendedProperty);
```

Thanx

Comment: i made changes.hope now you got the question

Comment: Looks like you copy & pasted your clients requirement directly.  The question is still unclear

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to [ContactEntry](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/contacts/ContactEntry.html) class and how to [update it](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Updating).

**RETRIEVE** your contact:

```
RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(this.ApplicationName, this.userName,this.passWord);      
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);  
Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/test@gmail.com/full/12345");
```

**UPDATE** your contact:

```
UserDefinedField customField= new UserDefinedField("yourFieldName","yourFieldValue);  
contact.addUserDefinedField(customField);  
Contact updatedContact = cr.Update(contact);
```

Comment: What is the "12345" in "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/test@gmail.com/full/12345"?

Comment: 12345 is Contact_ID