# Returning custom contact fields via the Google contacts api

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I have been unable to return any UserDefined/custom fields for a contact. I'm not even wanting to create or update an existing entry as per [Programatically adding "New Custom Field" To Google Contacts using Google contact API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515117/programatically-adding-new-custom-field-to-google-contacts-using-google-contac)

I have followed the guide here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference, but still to no avail.

I've called both

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json
```

and

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/DEADBEEF?alt=json
```

in an attempt to get ALL of the values returned. I thought I might have to call each contact id specifically to get the full details, but that doesn't work either.

DEADBEEF is clearly replaced with a valid contact id in my scenario.

/contacts/default determines that request should return contacts for the current auth'd user, which is myself in this case.

Has anyone managed to return custom values, is this even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, add the ?v=3.0 to the url string eg

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/DEADBEEF?alt=json&v=3.0
```

However, you should use the preferred method of adding a `GData-Version` header.